# AWS backend + react front end : handling request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, reactjs, aws-api-gateway

I'm messing around with AWS and I've set up a simple REST API using dynamodb, api gateway, and cognito.  I've written the REST API using node + express.

My node app is on EB, and basically I handle authentication of requests in API gateway using cognito.  As a standalone, this seems to be working fine as I'm testing it using a simple react app.

Now I'm doing server side rendering for my actual react app, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this.  For the server side rendering I have another node app called react-app-server, and I want to handle caching on the API gateway and use cloudfront for serving the static doc, images, etc.

So if I went to `www.mysite.com/for-sale/some-item-thats-for-sale`, this request should first check if there is a cached version of this page and serve it.  Otherwise, I need to have my react-app-server render the .html and serve/cache it.  Since there are two node applications, api-server and react-app-server, how can I point from my api-gateway to the react-app-server to render the html?

How does this scenario fit in with the AWS architecture?  I realize this might be a really stupid question but I am really new to this.  Thanks

Comment: Why would you have API Gateway serving HTML?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  as I mentioned I'm just a couple days into this for the first time and its a little embarassing for me since this is all new.  I'm trying to figure out how to handle having to render a page for the first time if it doesn't exist in cache.  For that, would I have to hit my `react-app-server` somehow and that's my disconnect.  So I'm thinking of using Lambda to execute my render function which would render the HTML and add it to cache, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: How is the HTML being cached exactly?

Comment: Right now I'm storing them in memory on node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you place Cloudfront in front of all your apps and allow Cloudfront to handle ALL of your caching using `Cache-Control` or an `Expires` header that you return on each HTML response. This will allow all the cached content to be returned from the Cloudfront edge servers improving performance and simplify your app a bit as well.

For example, if your node app returns an HTML document with a `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000` Header, Cloudfront will read that value and will return the same HTML response from the edge servers for up to 1 year (31,536,000 seconds = 1 year). If your node app returns an HTML document with a `Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600` Cloudfront will read that value and will cache the HTML for up to 1 hour at the edge servers.

You can have two (or more) origins defined in your distribution and you can use behaviors to control which origin each request would delegate to.

I actually just wrote a tutorial this AM on using Cloudfront in front of API Gateway: https://www.codeengine.com/articles/process-form-aws-api-gateway-lambda/. It's not identical to your use case but will help you get started if you're looking to use Cloudfront in front of API Gateway.

If you follow the tutorial a bit you can see that I'm serving most requests from an S3 bucket but routing paths starting with `/rest/` to API Gateway which is believe would work for your use case as well.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  That's a nice article.  I guess my big question would be I am rendering HTML on the node side, and rite now storing the rendered page in memory.  Would it be better if I export the rendered HTML to a s3 bucket, and then use cloud front?  Sorry I'm still confused a bit.. there's so much info :P  so basically client hits some page (looking at a used car or something) -> node renders that page if it dont exist -> right now just serving from memory, but instead put this into s3 then cloudfront?

Comment: I'm not sure the S3 layer would offer much advantage here unless you're planning to prime all the HTML in advance? If you just return the HTML from API Gateway with `Cache-Control` or an `Expires` header and configure Cloudfront to honor the origin headers it will cache the content at the edge and subsequent requests for the same HTML will not return to the origin (node API) until the expiration specified in those headers.

Comment: If on the other hand you're looking to build 100% of your HTML in advance on each deployment (like Jekyll does) then using an S3 bucket behind Cloudfront is definitely the way to go.

Comment: It's really a matter of whether you want a lazy cache (populated by web requests) or a primed cache (pre-populated on each deployment).

Comment: Thanks Dave!  I think I will use the cache-control method from your first reply as that is what I'm doing on the node end right now.  I'm invalidating the cache after 24 hours.  I will figure out how to do this from the API Gateway itself.  I want something like a lazy cache because my rationale is that a user will create a new listing, and upon creation I will need to cache that particular page.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront is a content delivery network which aims to minimize latency and transfer times for visitors from all parts of the world, by placing copies of your files in edge-locations. It has caching capabilities, so with the right setup you should be able to make it retrieve static content from your react-prerenderer and cache them.

The API Gateway is build to serve dynamic content and only runs in the main availability zones of AWS, not on edge locations. Routing a request via the API Gateway to CloudFront would be strange, if at all possible.

Another possibility is to handle cache in your application (e.g. in Express you could [use mcache](http://goenning.net/2016/02/10/simple-server-side-cache-for-expressjs/)).

Comment: Thanks! I am actually caching in my node app not using mcache just a simple dictionary.  Trying to learn how this all stuff fits together in the "real world" and its a lot to read :D  How do you handle serving correct HTML doc for a page, like if someone hits `/for-sale/some-item-123`, how do I send them the cached html for that?